# Calling PS1 script from other PS1 script failing after invoked for the 1st time in same Terminal instance, Why?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, command, command-line-interface

As per the image showing below, I have two PS1 script files.

1. `main.ps1` (from where we call the call.ps1 function)
2. `call.ps1`

Now, check the below SS for reference of structure - Both are on same Folder.

[image]

Now, When we call the `main.ps1` 1st time in **New Powershell** window it's working fine. (see blow)

[image]

Now the real issue is, If we call the same function again 2nd time it's not working and giving an error. (see below)

[image]

Am I missing something or understanding the things incorrectly? - Or this is not the way to call the PS1 from another PS1 file?

Surprisingly, If I close the existing Terminal and open New Terminal it works fine for the 1st time..!!!

[image]

Anyone has any clue what's wrong we're doing??

Comment: You can also dot-source the file instead of importing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone might write this better then me.

You need to rename `call.ps1` to `call.psm1`

Then change the code in `main.ps1` to the following

```
Import-Module '.\call.psm1'

callingthefunction
```

Also in your `main.ps1` you used `'./call.ps1'` the slash direction is wrong. Look at my code above.

For more information about modules which is what you are creating. Please read.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Wasn't expecting this easy resolution, Thanks dcaz for helping out and spend your time..!